# Issue with Ctrl + Arrow Keys in (Neo)vim using PuTTY

Tags: bash, vim, putty

When I establish a SSH connection to my machine using `PuTTY`, I find that the `Control + Arrow keys` behave unexpectedly when working with `vim` or `nvim` in the bash terminal.

For instance, in Vim, escaping `Ctrl + Left Arrow` and just the `Left Arrow` both output `^[OD`.

While in the case of Nvim, they both output `<left>`.

However, when I open `vim` or `nvim` inside `tmux`, the keys function as expected. In this case, the escaped `Control + Left Arrow` generates `^[[1;5D`, while the `Left Arrow` outputs `^[OD`.

In `nvim`, the corresponding outputs are `<C-Left>` and `<Left>` respectively.

---

I found a little workaround by ticking the box next to `Terminal > Features > Disable application cursor keys mode`. This enables proper functionality for the `Control + Arrow keys` in both `vim` and `nvim`, even outside of `tmux`.

Escaping `Control + Left Arrow` now results in `^[[1;5D`, and the `Left Arrow` yields `^[OD`. (Likewise with `nvim` returning `<C-left>` and `<left` respectively)

However, this change introduces a new issue. The arrow keys stop functioning when navigating through commands such as `top`, `htop`, `ranger`, or `man` (when inside `bash`). They still continue to work within `tmux`.

So, to address this, I attempted to add the following to `~/.inputrc`

```json
"\eOD": backward-word
"\eOC": forward-word
"\eOA": previous-history
"\eOB": next-history
```

Regrettably, this doesn't rectify the problem;

So, I'm hoping to find a solution that allows `Ctrl + Arrow keys` to function in `vim`/`neovim` within a standard `bash` environment, without compromising the scrolling functionality. Or, the other way around; Either goes...

### Tmux config:

```bash
$ echo $TERM
screen
```

```python
$ cat /usr/share/docs/tmux/example_tmux.conf

# Enable RGB colour if running in xterm(1)
set -ag terminal-overrides ",screen-256color:Tc"

# Change the default $TERM to tmux-256color
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

# Turn the mouse on, but without copy mode dragging
set -g mouse on
unbind -n MouseDrag1Pane
unbind -Tcopy-mode MouseDrag1Pane
```